# How do I validate start time and end time using select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have 2 really very big select boxes which I think is not the best approach for selecting the time. 
I have to restrict user from selecting start time lesser than end time. I mean the hours of operation during which my hotel is open. Here is what I have done using select.

```
<div class="weekends">
    <label for="">Weekdays</label>
    <select class="startTimeWeekDays" name="" id="">
        <option value="1am" <?php if( '1am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>1am</option>
        <option value="2am" <?php if( '2am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>2am</option>
        <option value="3am" <?php if( '3am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>3am</option>
        <option value="4am" <?php if( '4am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>4am</option>
        <option value="5am" <?php if( '5am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>5am</option>
        <option value="6am" <?php if( '6am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>6am</option>
        <option value="7am" <?php if( '7am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>7am</option>
        <option value="8am" <?php if( '8am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>8am</option>
        <option value="9am" <?php if( '9am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>9am</option>
        <option value="10am" <?php if( '10am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>10am</option>
        <option value="11am" <?php if( '11am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>11am</option>
        <option value="12am" <?php if( '12am'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>12am</option>
        <option value="1pm" <?php if( '1pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>1pm</option>
        <option value="2pm" <?php if( '2pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>2pm</option>
        <option value="3pm" <?php if( '3pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>3pm</option>
        <option value="4pm" <?php if( '4pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>4pm</option>
        <option value="5pm" <?php if( '5pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>5pm</option>
        <option value="6pm" <?php if( '6pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>6pm</option>
        <option value="7pm" <?php if( '7pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>7pm</option>
        <option value="8pm" <?php if( '8pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>8pm</option>
        <option value="9pm" <?php if( '9pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>9pm</option>
        <option value="10pm" <?php if( '10pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>10pm</option>
        <option value="11pm" <?php if( '11pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>11pm</option>
        <option value="12pm" <?php if( '12pm'== $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayStartTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>12pm</option>
    </select>
    <select class="endTimeWeekDays" name="" id="">
        <option value="1am" <?php if( '1am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>1am</option>
        <option value="2am" <?php if( '2am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>2am</option>
        <option value="3am" <?php if( '3am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>3am</option>
        <option value="4am" <?php if( '4am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>4am</option>
        <option value="5am" <?php if( '5am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>5am</option>
        <option value="6am" <?php if( '6am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>6am</option>
        <option value="7am" <?php if( '7am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>7am</option>
        <option value="8am" <?php if( '8am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>8am</option>
        <option value="9am" <?php if( '9am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>9am</option>
        <option value="10am" <?php if( '10am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>10am</option>
        <option value="11am" <?php if( '11am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>11am</option>
        <option value="12am" <?php if( '12am' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>12am</option>
        <option value="1pm" <?php if( '1pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>1pm</option>
        <option value="2pm" <?php if( '2pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>2pm</option>
        <option value="3pm" <?php if( '3pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>3pm</option>
        <option value="4pm" <?php if( '4pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>4pm</option>
        <option value="5pm" <?php if( '5pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>5pm</option>
        <option value="6pm" <?php if( '6pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>6pm</option>
        <option value="7pm" <?php if( '7pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>7pm</option>
        <option value="8pm" <?php if( '8pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>8pm</option>
        <option value="9pm" <?php if( '9pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>9pm</option>
        <option value="10pm" <?php if( '10pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>10pm</option>
        <option value="11pm" <?php if( '11pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>11pm</option>
        <option value="12pm" <?php if( '12pm' == $this->user->getConcept()->getWeekdayEndTime()): ?>selected<?php endif ?>>12pm</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I have to restrict user to choose end time greater than start time, lets say user selects 10am then must select greater than 10am or in terms of pm like real time. using jquery.
HERE IS WHAT YOU CAN SEE [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ne4ppkoe/)

Comment: You need to learn about loops, to avoid code repetition.

Comment: You need to use a `for ($i = 1; $i <=12; $i++)` in a function to get options. This is not a readable code.

Comment: Are you getting the time stamp in `getWeekdayEndTime()`? If In any case your getting time stamp, then it will be easy to find out which one is greater than.

Comment: I have only am and pm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To disable the endTime `option` with jQuery you can use this:

```
$(".startTimeWeekDays").change(function(){
   var startTime = $(this).val(); // Get the starting time

   // Reset disabled status
   $(".endTimeWeekDays option").prop("disabled", false);

   // Disable the end time options equal or less than selected time
   $(".endTimeWeekDays option[value='"+startTime+"']").next().prevAll().prop("disabled", true);
});
```

Comment: I want to validate not disable

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere You wrote it: _Now I have to restrict user to choose end time greater than start time_

Comment: @SudarshanKalebere can you explain "validate" please? A prompt message saying "The end time has to be greater than {startedTime}"?

Comment: Yes please check this approach here http://jsfiddle.net/Lpyk1fzu/ when I select 10am I agree it diasbled all time below 10am but again if I select 2 am than still it disables upto 10am only PLease check http://jsfiddle.net/Lpyk1fzu/

Comment: Yeah sorry, I did it in a hurry. Updated it, you just needed to remove the disabled property before.

Comment: Thanks but still if you see here same problem http://jsfiddle.net/0a9cyps1/

Comment: You're really fast! It was a mistake that I fix in 20 secs, but you already copied it. Sorry I'm getting busy. Try it now, it works, this time I tested it.

Comment: Actually I was trying with your code only, to disable props false before again applying it. so I was fast

Comment: Great Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  $("#checkin").on("change",function(){
    var chkIn = getValue($(this).val()), chkout = getValue($("#checkout").val())
    if(chkIn>=chkout) {
      alert("Checkin should be lesser than checkout");
      resetSelectedOptions();
    }

  })

  $("#checkout").on("change",function(){
    var chkout = getValue($(this).val()), chkIn = getValue($("#checkin").val())
    if(chkIn>=chkout) {
      alert("Checkin should be lesser than checkout");
      resetSelectedOptions()
    }

  })
})



function getValue(str){
  return str.indexOf("am")>-1?parseInt(str):parseInt(str)+12;
}

function resetSelectedOptions(){
    $("#checkout").val("1am");
    $("#checkin").val("1am")

}
```